# Separating grouped histogram data in rows in Stata

Tags: histogram, stata

I have some histogram data that needs transforming in order for me to use the Stata command `DCdensity`.

Here is the current form of the data:

```
-5--56-

-10--70-

-15--60-

-20--67-

-25--62-
```

But I need it such that I have 56 rows of 5, 70 rows of 10, 60 rows of 15 etc...
How could I make this transformation? The alternative is to edit the source code for the command but that would be far more complicated.

Comment: Similar post at https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1436083-dcdensity-mccrary-test-using-binned-frequency-data This is a long shot for Stack Overflow; you're asking people about a long program with no help file yet giving no data example. You're better off on Statalist where the chance is a bit higher that the question will be spotted by someone who has used the program and thus put in the time studying it.  That said, `help expand` may be what you want.

Comment: See `help dataex` in an up-to-date Stata (14.2 or 15.1 up), or failing that install with `ssc install dataex`, to see a way to give people example data that they can use directly.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested, you should use `expand`. Supposing that your variable is named `var1` this is how I would do it:

```
replace var1 = subinstr(subinstr(var1,"--","_",.),"-","",.)
split var1, p("_")
destring var1?, replace

expand var12
```

Comment: Helpful. My guess is that the OP was just using hyphens to give a crude table, but who knows until there is a really clear example.

Comment: Hi both! Thank you so much for the prompt reply. Yes that was just a crude table but the expand command has worked perfectly. This has saved me hours. Apologies for my sloppy writing up of the problem - I will be more concise and tidy next time